# Are Skeletron masks obtainable on mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was looking at [this wiki post](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mask), and it said that Skeletron masks are the only masks that can be obtained outside of PC. However, I was wondering if that meant that it is obtainable on mobile. It never says exactly what devices it is available on, so it might be possible, might not be. I have probably killed around 10 Skeletrons so far, but have had no luck receiving a mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Skeletron masks **are** obtainable on mobile. Maybe you just haven't had the best of luck so far, because it should be a 1/7 chance, but eventually you will find a mask that looks like this:
[image: Skeletron Mask]